# Test that a ZIP doesn't require zip64 support

Tags: python, zip, deflate

I'm looking to test some Python code makes zip files that dynamically chooses zip32 or zip64, and I would like to assert that in certain cases it really does create valid zip32 files by opening it in something that does not support zip64.

How can I check that a file really is openable by something that doesn't support zip64 in Python. The "allowZip64" option in Python's zipfile module seems to only be for writing, rather than reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

(I would prefer to not peek at the bytes of the file - I would like a more integration style test that uses existing library/software to process the file)

Comment: What about https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open?

Comment: @CristiFati I think there is no way to turn off zip64 support when reading files?

Comment: OK, what's the real problem here? Do you have some code that doesn't extract *2GiB+* files?

Comment: @CristiFati I'm writing a library that creates zip files. I want to make sure that when I think it's making a zip file that doesn't require zip64 support, that it really doesn't require zip64 support - and to do this via automated tests.

Comment: It's not very clear to me where exactly does the problem arise. The doc is clear. Check the packed item sizes and if one is more than 2Gib, then it requires the extensions.

Comment: Ah yes - but it's possible to make a small zip64 file. I want to make sure my library is _not_ doing that by opening the file using something that doesn't support zip64

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just get an old copy of the classic [PKZIP 2.04g executable](https://archive.org/details/PKWARE_version_2.04c). It should still run.

Or you can install a [version of Python before 2.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-243/), which is when Zip64 support in `zipfile` was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is somehow cheating, but as of a few minutes ago, the Python library stream-unzip supports *disabling* zip64 support by passing it `allow_zip64=False`

https://github.com/uktrade/stream-unzip/pull/46

Modifying an example from its docs:

```py
from stream_unzip import stream_unzip
import httpx

def zipped_chunks():
    with httpx.stream('GET', 'https://www.example.com/my.zip') as r:
        yield from r.iter_bytes(chunk_size=65536)

# Will raise UnsupportedZip64Error if trying to open a Zip64 file
for name, size, chunks in stream_unzip(zipped_chunks(), allow_zip64=False):
    for chunk in chunks:
        pass
```